# Return 0 when select returns nothing?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Say I have an array of hashes like so:

```
items = [
  {:user=>1, :amount=>484}, 
  {:user=>2, :amount=>0}, 
  {:user=>3, :amount=>8633}
]
```

To get the `amount` for a user, I'd so something like this:

```
items.select{|key| key[:user] == 1 }.first[:amount]
```

But if there isn't a `user` with a given ID, then that doesn't work:

```
> items.select{|key| key[:user] == 8 }.first[:amount]
# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

So how can I return `amount` if it finds the item, but return `0` if there's nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can use [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) instead of [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) since you only want the first match. If you want a one-liner, you can do something like this:

```
(items.find { |key| key[:user] == 8 } || { :amount => 0 })[:amount]
```

If you happen to have Rails or ActiveSupport kicking around then you could use [`try`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) and `to_i` (while remembering that `nil.to_i == 0`) like this:

```
items.find { |k| key[:user] == 1 }.try(:fetch, :amount).to_i
```

`try` just calls a method (`fetch` in this case) but always returns `nil` if the receiver is `nil` so `nil.try(:fetch, :amount)` is `nil` but `some_hash.try(:fetch, :amount)` is `some_hash.fetch(:amount)`, it is a handy tool for swallowing up `nil`s without adding a bunch of extra conditionals. AFAIK, the `andand` gem does similar things without requiring all the ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways:

**#1**

```
def my_method(user, items)
  items.each {|h|
    return h[:amount] if h.key?(:user) && h[:user] == user && h.key?(:amount)}
  0
end

my_method(1, items) #=> 484
my_method(5, items) #=>   0
```

**#2**

```
def my_method(user, items)
  items.reduce(0) { |v,h|
    (h.key?(:user) && h[:user] == user && h.key?(:amount)) ? h[:amount] : v }
end
```

**#3**

```
def my_method(user, items)
    hash = items.find { |h| h.key?(:user) && h[:user] == user) }
    (hash && hash.key?(:amount)) ? hash[:amount] : 0
end
```

Comment: You don't always need a one-liner :) I think we can assume that `hash.has_key? :amount` in this case and if not, you could use the `nil.to_i == 0` trick thusly: `hash[:amount].to_i` (assuming of course that no one has fiddled with `hash`'s default value...).

Comment: But it's a three-liner, μ.  I've gotten into the habit of using `key?` so I don't have to worry whether `nil` is a permitted value.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the **Exception NoMethodError**

```
begin
#code you want to execute
rescue NoMethodError
puts "0"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

put **rescue 0** on the end

```
items.select{|key| key[:user] == 8 }.first[:amount] rescue 0
```

Comment: No, please don't do this.  Inline rescues are a terrible idea in almost all cases.

Comment: I take it it makes debugging miserable.  Is that why?

Comment: first among equals is is that it absorbs ALL errors.  Items is not Enumerable? 0! Key is not a hash? 0! There are no results? 0!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant using some built-in Ruby fallback mechanisms

```
items.find(->{{}}){|e| e[:user] == 8}.fetch(:amount, 0)
```

First, starting from the end of the line, [`fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch), which returns the value at a provided hash key. One thing that makes `fetch` different from using regular hash square brackets is that, if the key isn't there, `fetch` throws as a key error instead of returning `nil`.  That's a neat trick, but the other useful thing is that it can take an optional second argument, which is the default thing to return if that key isn't found:

```
test = { a: 1, b:2 }
test[:c] #=> nil
test.fetch(:c) #=> raise KeyError
test.fetch(:c, 0) #=> 0
```

Handy, but you can't call `fetch` on nil, which is the default return for `find` if it finds nothing.

Luckily, [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) *also* lets you assign a default return value instead of nil. You can pass an object that responds to `call`, and that object will specify how to handle a find with no matches.

Here's a short lambda that returns an empty hash: `->{{}}` and here it is passed as a first argument to `find`, before the usual block

```
items.find(->{{}}){ |key| key[:user] == 8 } #=> {}
```

All together: `items.find(->{{}}){|e| e[:user] == 8}.fetch(:amount, 0)` -- now `find` will always return some sort of hash, which will respond to `fetch`, and fetch can return a default if a key is missing.